# How to uncheck radio Button using code in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have 8 radio buttons in my program, I want to reset all the radio buttons when clicking a Reset All button, Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Just called `.clearCheck()` to your `RadioGroup`

```
RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
radioGroup2.clearCheck();
```

Answer (score 1):

For separate RadioButtons:

```
//Inside onClick of ClearAll button
rb1.setChecked(false);
rb2.setChecked(false);
rb3.setChecked(false);
rb4.setChecked(false);
rb5.setChecked(false);
rb6.setChecked(false);
rb7.setChecked(false);
rb8.setChecked(false);
```

For RadioButtons inside RadioGroup:

```
//Inside onClick of ClearAll button
rg.clearCheck();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is much better use CheckBox for this purposes